# Is there something like object.toJSON in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using ES6 I transpile using Babel into ordinary JavaScript.

I want to serialise objects into JSON format and am wondering if ES5,ES6 offers a convenient function to do so.

For `Maps` and `Sets` there is a `toJSON()`-function proposed in ES7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and pass any kind of variable to it (given that it can be represented in JSON).

It works in all current browsers; in case you need a fallback for a *really* old browser, you can use [Crockford's JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

However, keep in mind that, regarding objects, only public properties are serialized. There's no a generic way to serialize function variables etc. on the fly.

This is why some special object types provide a `toJSON` or similar method. In order to use such a function for arbitrary objects, you must pass a function as second parameter to `JSON.stringify` which checks for the existence of a `toJSON` function.

For example, the following should work (not tested, just from the top of my mind):

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(someLargeObject, function(key, value){
    return (value && typeof value.toJSON === 'function') 
        ? value.toJSON()
        : JSON.stringify(value);
});
```

If your `someLargeObject` contains a sub-object with a `toJSON` method, this code would use the object's implementation, otherwise use `JSON.stringify`.